# Module build error

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to setup a WebpackBin because I need help eventually with a question I will post in the future (I would like to be able to provide some code to check out and debug instead of just code to guess) but I am getting a lint error that I am not getting in my actual app.

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (107:10)

  105 |   
  106 | 
  107 |  onChange = (event, { newValue, method }) => {
      |           ^
  108 |     this.setState({
  109 |     value: newValue
  110 |     });
```

Here is the [**webpackBin**](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KkfPUZx1-MYo9aC8zG-)

Once it's error free, I will post my actual question/problem I am having.

As a side note, this should work as it is. It is working for me in my app. I haven't added the problem area to this code yet. I will do that once this runs and then post the question.

This is what it should look like after it runs (minus the styling)[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: you just have to enable `stage-0` or `Class properties` in your webpackbin configuration to get rid of that error

Comment: @QoP Bingo! You should answer this question man. Maybe a quick explanation as to how stage=0 or class properties work. I wouldn't mind understading and learning instead of just coding mechanically :) I'll credit you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to enable `stage-0` or `Class properties transform` in your webpackbin configuration to get rid of that error.

What you got here `onChange = (event, { newValue, method }) =>` is a mix of

1. [arrow functions](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-arrow-functions/)
2. [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)

which are just syntactic sugar for "standard js".

You can achieve the same thing without using them.

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component{

   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
   }

   onChange(event, { newValue, method }){
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

About [stage-0](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/), when you add it to your babel configuration, you are including all the [experimental](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets-stage-x-experimental-presets-) plugins available.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions inside the class are declared wrong syntactically, you should this syntax:

```
 onChange = (event, { newValue, method }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
 };
```

To this syntax:

```
 onChange(event, { newValue, method }) {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
 };
```

[Updated Bin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kkf_9oMDU1KEokp5ujM)

Comment: I did that previously, and got this 

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

In fact, it is happening in your edit when I try to run the autosuggest

Comment: You probably called a function that uses `setState` without binding `this` to it, or outside of an arrow function call. Look at the updated bin link I added, it works. What you did afterwards that caused the error is a different matter.

Comment: I looked at the updated bin link you added. It doesn't work. This works in my app as I showed in the screenshot. It also accepts the syntax I initially wrote. Refer to this http://react-autosuggest.js.org/ and also the codepen they provide to see the code for a basic example here http://codepen.io/moroshko/pen/LGNJMy?editors=0010